# spring boot with docker compose configured: services must be a mapping

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose

I created a sping-boot app with spring initializer, with Docker Compose Support added.
Generated project has an empty compose.yaml, as I havent added nothing to project yet.

When I try to run app in IDE(intellij) i get error:

```
Stderr:
validating ..../compose.yaml: services must be a mapping

    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:96) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.3.0-20240301.111245-172.jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli.run(DockerCli.java:80) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.3.0-20240301.111245-172.jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add following line in compose.yaml file.

```
version: '1.0'
```

it will solve your problem if you don't want to add any configuration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As there's no line reference in the error, but from what it says, it seems you are writing the services with a syntax error.

Often this error refers to adding a reference in the form of an array, in this way:

```
foo:
 - bar
```

when it should be a map, in this way:

```
foo:
  bar:
```

You can check the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to see what each area of the compose file expects.

As it refers to services, it is expected they are added in this way:

```
services:
  example:
    image: image-name:tag
```

with many variations in terms of each value.